# How to check for a field existence in a type possibly using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

I have a struct called Traits which is template with type T, Traits has a single field called Size. When T actually has a field called Size the code compiles and everything works well. However, when T is a native type it obviously doesn't have Size field and the code fails to compile

```
template <class T>
struct Traits
{
    static const size_t Size = T::Size;
};
```

I tried to write it using SFINAE but it still won't compile

```
template <class T>
struct Traits
{
    static typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, const size_t>::type Size = T::Size;
    static typename std::enable_if< std::is_fundamental<T>::value, const size_t>::type Size = sizeof(T);
};
```

The compilation error is

```
error : redeclaration of `typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, const unsigned int>::type Traits<T>::Size'
```

This doesn't make any sense since the compiler thinks I'm redeclaring Size but actually it is not possible since T is either fundamental type or not so I expect Size to be declared only once.

Any idea what is wrong or how to circumvent this issue? (using gcc 4.8.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE only works in certain contexts and this is not one of them. SFINAE can only be used in the context of class template specialization and function template signatures. Move the test into a class template specialization and it should work as expected:

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct Traits  //default is is fundamental
{
    static const size_t Size = sizeof(T);
};
template<class T>
struct Traits<T,std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>>{ //if SFINAE does not remove this it is not fundamental and should have a T::Size
    static const size_t Size = T::Size;
}
```

It might be better to directly test if T has a nested Size using a void_t:

```
template<typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <class T, class = void>
struct Traits  //default 
{
    static const size_t Size = sizeof(T);
};
template<class T>
struct Traits<T,void_t<decltype(T::Size)>>{ //if SFINAE does not remove this T::Size exists
    static const size_t Size = T::Size;
}
```